# how can i stop a while loop background process without using kill?

Tags: bash, shell-script

i have a bash script with a **while loop** background processes how can i stop the while loop without kill the process so by set a **STOP** flag

Note: my script is works if i use **kill** but with **stop flag** didn't work

this is a demo of my script(using Kill):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash


background_processes=()


trap ctrl_c INT
ctrl_c() {
    printf "\n[~] Killing background processes...\n"
    for pid in "${background_processes[@]}"
        do
          kill $pid > /dev/null 2>&1
        done

}

background_process() {
    while true
        do
         sleep 5
         printf "Hello World!\n"
        done

}

start() {

    for t in $(seq 1 10)
        do 
            background_process &
            background_processes+=(${!})
        done

    wait
}
printf "\n[I] Press 'ctrl+c' to kill background processes! \n"
start
```

This one works fine but the other method not work !

This is my same demo but with stop flag(**not work**!)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash


STOP=0
threads=10
finished_threads=0

trap ctrl_c INT
ctrl_c() {
    printf "\n[~] Stopping background processes...\n"
    STOP=1
    # here i was checking that all the background processes is finish
    while true
        do
         if [[ $finished_threads == $threads ]]
             then
                break
         fi
        done
    printf "\n[+] Done\n"
 

}

background_process() {
    while true
        do
         sleep 5
         printf "Hello World!\n"
         if [[ $STOP = 1 ]]
             then
                ((finished_threads++))
                break
         fi
        done

}

start() {

    for t in $(seq 1 $threads)
        do 
            background_process &
        done

    wait
}
printf "\n[I] Press 'ctrl+c' to stop background processes! \n"
start
```

Can anyone tell me why this not works please ?

P.S: i am arabian btw so sorry if my English grammar is not good

Comment: the best way to control a loop is to set up a dedicated *signal* for that, in fact 2 one to check loop is running & one to be intercepted by the loop itself to exit properly.  see 7th page of signal manual to choose the good one for your needs & trap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the second example doesn't work, is that each process has its own address space, so setting the value to the `$STOP` variable in the main process doesn't affect the value read by the background processes.

The straightforward way of terminating the background workers is to use signals, as you are doing in the first example. An alternative way would be to use pipes for the synchronization, e.g by having the child processes use non-blocking read, the parent closing the pipe when it wants to terminate, and the children exiting when detecting that the pipe had been closed.

Comment: but i don't want to terminate them i just want them to stop by breaking the while loop, for example in ```python```  this works, is this the only way to stop while loop background?
or my second example somehow can work by editing something in it ?

Comment: @Ahmed in python you are probably using threads instead of processes, so then you can have shared memory. If you don't want the child processes to terminate when receiving the signal, you can trap it, like you are already doing in the parent.

Comment: is there an way to make them have a shared memory like threads ?

Comment: @Ahmed, no I don't think that threads are available in the shell

Comment: i don't mean using threads, i mean is there an alternative of shared memory to make them works this way in second example  ?

Comment: Another option would be to use `/dev/shm/` directory as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849183/how-to-implement-shared-memory-in-shell-scripting#comment88701948_50849183

Comment: this exactly what i am looking for thank you so much Mr. @user000001 :)